# Convert date into mysql format

Tags: php

Hello i am trying to convert this date.

```
01. 06. 2015
```

Into mysql format, so i can insert it into database.

I tried this code, and other ombination with date and date format function.

```
`$mysqldate = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($datefrom));`
```

but i get result

`1.1.1970`

Is it possible to do this with some date function, or i must use regex for resolving this problem. Maybe dateformat function?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp

Comment: You could explode it, trim it and then use `mktime()` to generate a valid date. As it is it is not a format that is recognized by `strtotime()`. You could also generate a DateTime object from a specific format but then the format would have to be exactly fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this.. works fine

```
$datefrom = "01. 06. 2015";
$datefrom = str_replace( ". ", "-", $datefrom);
$mysqldate = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($datefrom));
```

Comment: That would depend on what the first and second numbers are exactly: d M or M d.

Comment: Its ok for format like d m Y...

Comment: tnx vote up my question i accepted yours and vote uped

Answer (score 2):

you need to clean your dateformat

```
  <?php
     $date = '01. 06. 2015';
     $date = str_replace(' ', '', $date); // replace whitespaces
     $mysqldate = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date));
```

Comment: That would depend on what the first and second numbers are exactly: d M or M d.

Comment: strtotime uses eg. germanformat dd.mm.yyyy or is able to use engformat mm-dd-yyyy ;)

Comment: Very true, I wonder if that is actually the format that the OP is using.

Comment: tnx i vote up your question, but i must accept answer before. vote up my question tnx